# Will the Swift 4 array built in method "min()" and "max()" work on an array of strings?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swift4, min

Below is the playground code which takes a string and splits it based on the empty spaces and creates an array. On what basis does the function calculates the min & max value in an array of strings. Is it the string length? I am expecting the result based on string length. Correct me if that is not the expected behaviour.

```
let testString = "swim switch swill swift"
let wordArray = testString.components(separatedBy: " ")
let first = wordArray.min()!
```

Comment: Instead of asking "will it work?", why not try to run it in a playground?

Comment: @Sweeper I did run that in playground but I was not getting the expected result. I have edited the description now. I am not sure on what basis the function works. Please let me know if you have any idea on that.

Comment: You already have two good answers and you can also do `print(wordArray.sorted(by: <))` to make it even clearer what min and max are

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not solely based on string length.

If you command+click the word `min` and then press "Jump to Definition", you will see that it is declared in an extension of `Array`:

```
extension Array where Element : Comparable {
    ...
```

This suggests that the way it compares the elements is probably using `<` and `>`, since those are the operators required by `Comparable`.

Therefore, the `min` method will return the "smallest" string based on comparisons with the `<` operator.

How does the `<` operator work with strings then?

These all evaluate to true:

```
"s" < "ss"
"a" < "b"
"ab" < "b"
```

Which suggests that it compares the letters alphabetically first, then by length. In other words, it works like a dictionary (as in an actual dictionary with words and their meanings, not the data structure). The `min` method will return the word that will appear the first in a dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

It accepts min and max but it works in **alphabetical order**.

```
import UIKit
let testString = "s ab dfc rtgf"
let wordArray = testString.components(separatedBy: " ")
let first = wordArray.min()! // prints ab
let second = wordArray.max()! // prints s
```